# Notify us when the recipient of a comments to chat replies

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

*I do not get a notification when someone responds to me in a chat (which has been moved from the comments section). The recipient doesn't receive a notification either, as in the past, I've had to prompt them in a comment that I have responded to the chat.*

In my opinion, it would be useful to receive a notification when the recipient of a chat moved from the comments section replies. This is because some people are not aware that you have to ping the person for a notification to appear.

---

*Q: Do you suggest this be the case even if/when a third person joins the chat? Anyone can join a chat moved from the comments, so long as the link is there in the comments. It's not limited to the original commenters*

*A: I think only the original commenters should receive a notification (which they have the ability to opt out of) and other people that join have to be pinged, or can opt in to receive notifications.. something like that.*

Comment: Do you suggest this be the case even if/when a third person joins the chat? Anyone can join a chat moved from the comments, so long as the link is there in the comments. It's not limited to the original commenters.

Comment: @Kendra It depends, really. I think only the original commenters should receive a notification _(which they have the ability to opt out of)_ and other people that join have to be pinged, or can opt in to receive notifications.. something like that.